# Select distinct add a order by query based on the count of a bookmarked product

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that basically give me unique counts of bookedmarked items

```
select DISTINCT ON (variant_id) variant_id, Count(wl) as count, pds.name AS name,
      CASE
          WHEN pvs.name is NULL THEN pds.name
          ELSE pvs.name
      END 
      as variant_name,
      im.url as img_url
    from wish_lists as wl
    LEFT JOIN products AS pds ON pds.id = wl.product_id
    LEFT JOIN images as im on im.product_id = wl.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_variants as pvs ON pvs.id = wl.variant_id
    where to_date(wl.created_at::TEXT,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2023-02-01' AND to_date(wl.created_at::TEXT,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2023-02-21' AND wl.tenant_id=91
    group by ( variant_id, pds.name, im.url, pvs.name) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

The problem is i want the `ORDER BY` to be `count`, so right now i get results like below :-

[image]

But actually the product 811 should be at the top cause it has a count of 2. So how extract do i go about doing `order by` on a `select distinct` query ? I.E. The bookmarked items with the highest counts should come on top.

Edit I tried adding `order by count desc` just towards the end of the query but ran into the following error.

> ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY
> expressions LINE 1: select DISTINCT ON (variant_id) variant_id,
> Count(wl) as cou...

Comment: "_i want the ORDER BY ..._" Include an ORDER BY in the sql query in your posted question, please. You can use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) WITH clause if you like. Or a correlated subquery.

Comment: What happened when you tried to add `order by variant_id, count(wl) desc)`?

Comment: Btw: there is no need to enclose the columns of a GROUP BY in parentheses (in fact it's an error as you are now grouping by single column which is an anonymous record type).

Answer (score 0):

try move all in inner query like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
---Your Query---
) a ORDER BY a.count
```